# Salto de línea en el multiline text (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un código de comunicación serial UART en *Android Studio* para celular. Para ver los datos que recibo por el puerto serie del celular utilizo el siguiente código:

```
public static String bytesToString(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : data) {
        response.append(String.format("%c", b)).append("");
    }
    return response.toString().trim();
}
```

Estoy usando un Multiline Text para colocar todo lo que recibo por el puerto serie usando el siguiente código:

```
if (data != null) {        
    txTEXT.setText(txTEXT.getText()+Utilities.bytesToString(data)+"\r\n");
}
```

El problema que tengo es que el la información que se ve en el Multiline Text se ve así:

```
Line
a
1
```

```
Linea
2
```

Yo quiero ver la información así:

```
Linea 1
Linea 2
```

¿Alguien puede indicarme que puedo hacer para este caso?

Comment: Y estás seguro que en `data` tienes "Linea 1" cuando llamas a `bytesToString`? O no será que entre "Linea" y el "1" hay un salto de línea?

Comment: Cuando quito el \r\n despues de llamar al bytestoString, sale todo de corrido : sale como Linea1 Linea2, el problema es cuando le coloco \r\n da como resultado el caso que menciono arriba.

Comment: Si quitas eso, obviamente sale todo seguido, pero eso no responde a mi pregunta. Entiendo que a eso vas llamando en un bucle, la primera vez te llega Linea y lo imprimes, la siguiente el 1 y lo imprimes, luego Linea, y lo mismo. Si no pones el salto de linea no lo ves, pero si lo pones, ves que en cada llamada que haces te llega solo una parte del texto y no es la que tú crees. Pon trazas de lo que tienes en data y verás.

Comment: Como estás leyendo los datos? con un Thread fuera del principal? si es así lo que puede estar pasando, es que cuando lees la info, no ha llegado por completo, yo recomendaría elegir una caracter o una serie de caracteres, para indicar final de transmision, de esta forma creas un buffer que se va llenando hasta detectar el fin de linea, y solo entonces, imprimes la data